# How to show time on ListWeek in FullCalendar using VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Can anyone have idea how to show time in List View For Full-Calendar. Everything is working fine for me but time itself is not coming in the view. Attached the snaps for the reference.

[image]

**CODESANDBOX LINK** : https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-fullcalendar-scheduler-example-forked-204qy?file=/components/Calendar.vue

Code:
Template:  
Script:

```
    data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: "listWeek",
        headerToolbar: {
          left: "today prev,next",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek",
        },
        events: [
          {
            start: "2021-11-10T04:30:00",
            title: "List View",
            backgroundColor: '#226911',
            end: "2021-11-27T14:30:00",
          },
          {
            start: "2021-11-08T04:30:00",
            title: "Test",
            end: "2021-11-10T14:30:00",
          },
          {
            start: "2021-10-15T04:30:00",
            title: "It should be default load",
            end: "2021-10-18T14:30:00",
          },
        ],
        eventDisplay: "block",
        displayEventTime: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        buttonText: {
          today: "Today",
          month: "Month",
          week: "Week",
          day: "Day",
          list: "Agenda",
        },
      },
    };
  }

enter code here
```

Please review the code and help me to out from this issue. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You've specifically written `displayEventTime: false`...what are you expecting this to do?? The clue is very much in the name, and also in the documentation... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventTime . Did you not review all the lines in your code before posting this? Did you not think to check the meaning of each line in the documentation if you weren't sure? It's a pretty basic and obvious process you need to go through, and you don't have a lot of fullCalendar code there to review...

Answer (score 2):

maybe set displayEventTime to true in calendarOptions

Comment: Thanks @Hyperalla . Issue resolved Now!